# Replace each directory with the sole regular file it contains

Tags: bash, file-rename

I need to rename files in multiple directories to the name of the parent directory and move them up one directory and the delete the empty directories.

Sample structure:

```
/export
   exp_20210101
      3747-46473-328383-5555
   exp_20210102
      4533-45323-354345-5366
```

Desired result:

```
/export
   exp_20210101
   exp_20210102
```

`3747-46473-328383-5555` renamed to `exp_20210101`

No extensions (Linux)
I prefere to do it with a bash script.

Already tried several samples (similar questions), but they're not working for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to rename files in multiple directories to the name of the parent directory and move them up one directory and the delete the empty directories.

I don't think that's possible, you can't have a regular file and a directory with the same name in the same directory.

You should move each file to the same level as its parent without changing its name instead (assuming a file with the same name may not exist there). Then you can remove the parent and rename the file to its name.

```
for f in /export/*/*; do
  echo mv "$f" "${f%/*/*}"
  echo rmdir "${f%/*}"
  echo mv "${f%/*/*}/${f##*/}" "${f%/*}"
done
```

Drop `echo`s if the output looks good.